# How to display selected value on same page

Tags: c#, javascript, php, html, web-services

This is my code

```
<?

$your_file = "tmp1.txt";

   //open the file
   $read_your_file = @fopen($your_file, "r") or die ("Couldn't Access $your_file");

   //create a variable to hold the contents of the file
$contents_your_file = fread($read_your_file, filesize($your_file));

//array of file contents
$your_array = explode("\n",$contents_your_file);

//close the file
fclose($read_your_file);

//counts the number elements in the property_categories array
$num_elmnts_array = count($your_array) ;

//elements in the drop down list
//$drop_elmnts = 0;

//begin creating your dropdown menu...

$your_menu = "<select name=\"list\">";  
//For loop to begin
for($counter = 0; $counter < $num_elmnts_array; $counter++){
   $your_menu .= "<option value=\"$your_variable\">$your_array[$counter]</option>";
    //$counter++;
}
//end select menu
$your_menu .= "</select>";

?>



<p><b>Here is my Menu</b><br>
<? echo "$your_menu"; 
?>
```

This code helps to list the words from a txt file in html listbox. I have a doubt in display of selected value. its output is only display a selection box which contains words in a text file. Now i want to display selected word. If i got selected option from the listbox, then i can display and assign a task on every words.

please help me to display a selected word in a same page. or another page (post method).

Comment: on next page: if(isset($_POST['list'])) echo $_POST['list'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you are looking like this:
<script>
function getSelectedValue(theValue){
document.getElementById('pasteTheValue').innerHTML=theValue;
}
</script>
<?php
$your_file = "file.txt";

//open the file
$read_your_file = @fopen($your_file, "r") or die ("Couldn't Access $your_file");

//create a variable to hold the contents of the file
$contents_your_file = fread($read_your_file, filesize($your_file));

//array of file contents
$your_array = explode("\n",$contents_your_file);

//close the file
fclose($read_your_file);

//counts the number elements in the property_categories array
$num_elmnts_array = count($your_array) ;

//elements in the drop down list
//$drop_elmnts = 0;

//begin creating your dropdown menu...

$your_menu = "<select name=\"list\" onchange=\"getSelectedValue(this.value)\">";  
//For loop to begin
for($counter = 0; $counter < $num_elmnts_array; $counter++){
   $your_menu .= "<option value=\"$your_array[$counter]\">$your_array[$counter]    </option>";
    //$counter++;
}
//end select menu
$your_menu .= "</select>";
?>
<p><b><?php echo "$your_menu"; ?></b><br>
<p id="pasteTheValue"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you mam. It works. Here you mentioned pasteTheValue is selected value from the listbox. Can i use this same in JSP. like

  <%String[] command = {"/bin/bash", "$pasteTheValue".sh};
    ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process p2 = p.start();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
    String line = br.readLine();
    
    System.out.println("Output of running " + command + " is: " + line);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
            %>

to run shell script.